# Получаю объект не того типа при запросе из redux

Tags: angular, объекты, redux

Использую ngrx. В `State` одно поле `productFilters: Filters`. В `initialState` инициализирую `productFilters: new Filters()`

Класс `Filters`:

```
export class Filters {
  field1 = new FilterParam();
  field2 = new FilterParam();
  field3 = new FilterParam();
  field4 = new FilterParam();
  field5 = new FilterParam();
  field6 = new FilterParam();
  field7 = new FilterParam();
  field8 = new FilterParam();
}

export class FilterParam {
  allSelected: boolean = false;
  payload: number[] = [];
}
```

По селектору из `store` запрашиваю `getProductFilters`. Мне приходит не `Filters`, а `Object` с теми же самыми полями, которые тоже типа `Object`.

**В чём может быть проблема?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема решилась с помощью чистки `localStorage`

localStorage чистится в консоли разработчика(F12), вкладка `Storage`

[image]